# Laravel 5.2 can not set config value

Tags: laravel, config

I have the problem that I can not set my configuration values through the config() function.

I have my own config file (cms.php in config/). The value I want to change is 'index'.

In my ConfigController I try to set the value with this:

```
config(['cms.index' => $page_id]);
```

Any solutions? Do I have to import a special class?

Comment: Do you want to override config values for just one request or save it in your `cms.php` so it can be used over multiple requests?

Answer (score 6):

`config(['cms.index' => $page_id]);` will set the value for runtime only. It won't save it to the config file.

If you want persistent configurations take a look at [Update Config on Runtime Persistently](http://heera.it/laravel-tips-update-config-runtime-persistently)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to \Config::set('cms.index', $page_id);